# After installing Ubuntu 14.04 over 12.04, it boots straight to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

even though I have windows 8.1 installed on separate partition. how can I boot to windows, or preferably, how can I be able to choose which OS to boot via grub? Lenovo Y580

EDIT: i wasn't updating to 14.04, I did a fresh install over 12.04

Comment: To clarify, is it that Windows is not listed in grub, or that you do not receive a grub screen at all?

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

You'll want to make sure 14.04 did not completely wipe Windows. You can do this by going into Grub and checking to see if there are any other OS-es/installations it will allow you to boot into. And if Windows is still there, Grub's menu will allow you to actually boot it. Or it should.